# Add to value if dictionary key exists

Tags: vb.net

I'm looping through a list of orders, and adding `Sku` and `Qty` to a dictionary. If the dictionary key is already present, then I want to add the `Qty` to the existing value. Having trouble coming up with the correct syntax. For example, when looping through this list:

```
Sku: "ABC", Qty: 1
Sku: "XYZ", Qty: 3
Sku: "ABC", Qty: 1
```

On the duplicate `Sku` of "ABC", it would update the existing `Qty` to 2.

Code:

```
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of string, Int16) = New Dictionary(Of string, Int16)()

If dict.ContainsKey(order.Sku) Then
    dict(order.Sku) = 'What goes here?
Else
    dict.Add(order.Sku, order.Qty)
End If
```

Comment: `dict(order.Sku) += order.Qty`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already I would suggest turning **[Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)**.

This code:

```
dict(order.Sku) += 1
```

With **[Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)**, will produce the following compile error:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer' to 'Short'

You have an option of changing your `dict` to be `(Of String, Integer)` and that would fix that issue. Or you could go down the route of converting to a `Short`:

```
dict(order.Sku) += CShort(1)
```

*If* `order.Qty` is type `Int32` then you probably won't see any issues with:

```
dict(order.Sku) += order.Qty
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Int16) = New Dictionary(Of String, Int16)()

If dict.ContainsKey(order.Sku) Then
    dict(order.Sku) += 1 'or += order.Qty if you want to add as much as in the order
Else
    dict.Add(order.Sku, order.Qty)
End If
```

`dict(order.Sku)` will index the `Int16` object you want to increase.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Int16) = New Dictionary(Of String, Int16)()

If dict.ContainsKey(order.Sku) Then
    dict(order.Sku) = dict(order.Sku) + order.Qty 'Assuming order.Qty is new quantity to be added
Else
    dict.Add(order.Sku, order.Qty)
End If
```